# command line expand overwritten

Tags: windows, command-prompt, archive

[Not sure if this is the right place for this question, if not, please correct me!]

I am having frequent BSOD issues with my graphics card driver. On closer inspection, it turns out there is an issue with a driver file called atikmpag.sys - an issue that other people have apparently faced many times before. I found a workaround on [this website](http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/719321-amd-atikmpag-sys-atikmdag-sys-bsod-fix.html). In short, the thing I need to do is expand the driver file `atikmpag.sy_` to `atikmpag.sys`. This should be done with the following command line (I have put the file `atikmpag.sy_` in a folder called `C:\test`):

```
cd C:\test
expand atikmpag.sy_ atikmpag.sys
```

however, when I execute those two lines, I get a LOT of beeping noises accompanied with the following screen:

[image: Image during crash]

After some time, the command line will start responding again and I am left with the message 'atikmpag.sys: no such file or directory' (see image below)

[image: Image after crash]

Upon running `expand /?` I found that the `/?` flag was not recognized by command prompt. I needed to call `expand --help`, which showed me the following screen:

[image]

It seems to me that I probably installed some program that overwrote the standard windows `expand` command prompt function and replaced it with some tab-removal functionality. Now my question is: how can I restore/access the original windows function? Or alternatively: is there any other way I can extract the original `atikmpag.sy_` file to `atikmpag.sys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong expand (the one which expands tabs to spaces, which makes no sense since this is a binary).

You should be using the one from the windows directory, `C:\Windows\System32\expand.exe`. If you've lost it try `sfc /scannow` if you haven't already, or if you need it quick grab it from one of the internet's download sites, and hope it's not riddled with malware.